# Laravel Spark 6.0 Ajax request unauthenticated

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-spark

I am building an app from a vanilla Spark 6.0 installation. I can login, access the Kiosk and click around.

I have created a new Card section with a form and am using the SparkForm object as directed by the [documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/forms); however every single request returns unauthenticated and thus I have to re-login.

I cannot get the ajax request to authenticate. I have created a seperate adminApi to handle admin ajax request which is protected by auth/dev/web middleware.

Any ideas/pointer much appreitated.

Relevent Code:

RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

    $this->mapApiRoutes($router);

    $this->mapAdminApiRoutes($router);

    //
}
...
protected function mapAdminApiRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'middleware' => ['dev', 'auth', 'web'],
        'prefix' => 'admin/api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/adminApi.php');
    });
}
```

routes/adminApi.php

```
Route::resource('/insurers', 'Admin\InsurersController');
```

vue component - insurers.js

```
var base = require('kiosk/users');

Vue.component('spark-kiosk-insurers', {
    mixins: [base],
    data: function() {
        return {
            showingInsurerProfile: false,
            form: new SparkForm({
                name: '',
                email:'',
                logo:''
            })
        }
    },
    props: {
        insurer: {}
    },
    methods: {
        search: function() {

        },
        create: function() {
            Spark.post('/admin/api/insurers', this.form)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        },

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSRF Token to the form like

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then add the following to your request:

```
headers: {
 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'Token Here' // from meta
```

}

Comment: HI, Spark already sorts that out for you as part of Spark.post() I will add the csfr token manually to the form and see what happens.